# Preserve host security with non root Docker containers

Tags: security, docker, namespaces

I'm a teacher that needs to allow his students to create Docker containers using non-admin accounts, while preserving the host safety and security.

From what I understand, I can set up the docker environment to use user-namespace (userns) by default, this should grant the students root identity in containers while mapping to a regular non-root user on the host machine. But how can I deny them the ability to skip this user remapping if they use a "--userns=host" option?